# After upgrading to target level 12, lots of anr in app

Tags: android

I am not able to repro any ANR in our app. Before upgrading to target 12 everything was fine but after upgrading to 12, many ANR are reported on firebase crashlytics.

```
    ANR 1:

    main (native): tid=1 systid=32245
    #00 pc 0x9fc58 libc.so
    #01 pc 0x1663c libutils.so
    #02 pc 0x16520 libutils.so
    #03 pc 0x152b78 libandroid_runtime.so
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:186)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8633)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)


    ANR 2:
    queued-work-looper (native): tid=16 systid=25495
    #00 pc 0xd7b88 libc.so
    #01 pc 0x474c libopenjdkjvm.so
    #02 pc 0x1e088 libopenjdk.so
    at java.io.FileDescriptor.sync(FileDescriptor.java)
    at android.os.FileUtils.sync(FileUtils.java:245)
    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.writeToFile(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:807)
    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.access$900(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:59)
    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$2.run(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:672)
    at android.app.QueuedWork.processPendingWork(QueuedWork.java:264)
    at android.app.QueuedWork.access$000(QueuedWork.java:50)
    at android.app.QueuedWork$QueuedWorkHandler.handleMessage(QueuedWork.java:284)
```

These ANR are mainly reported on Android OS version 11 and higher. Does anyone face same issue?

Comment: Do you have webviews in your app?

Comment: @Hype yes, Is there any relation of these ANR to webviews.

Comment: @d.k. Anything you could find ? There are a loads of issues on our side too, Reason is unknown

Comment: @Hype Whats the relation to webviews ?

Comment: @Yogurt
Check this out:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/230950647
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1306508#c48

Answer (score 0):

Here's a FAQ about what causes these issues:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jN4itpCe_bDXF0BhFaYwv4xVLsCWkL9eULdzjmLzkuk/edit#

Issue tracker tickets:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/230950647

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1306508#c48